# 5+ minutes long performance loss with $_SESSION (php 5.4.3)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, session

It's been three days I'm working here to fix this.

When I use my functions like this, it takes php to respond in 5+ minutes!

```
$indexContent = $class->myWall($_SESSION['FUID'], 20, 'no', 15, 'no');
$fUser = $class->getUser($_SESSION['FUID']);
```

but if I use like this, everythings normal takes 250ms to load.

```
$indexContent = $class->myWall(1, 20, 'no', 15, 'no');
$fUser = $class->getUser(1);
```

What's going wrong here? Where is the problem? I tried to upgrade/downgrade php version, mysql version etc but no effect.

Comment: What is inside myWall and getUser methods?

Comment: what does print_r($_SESSION) output

Comment: just basic mysql select queries for example: `SELECT * FROM updates LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=updates.user_id WHERE updates.update_id='$update_id'`

Comment: @AliDemirci Exactly this is a problem. Executing this query takes more than 5 monutes. Do you have indexes on `users.user_id` and `updates.user_id`?

Comment: i am quite sure that `$_SESSION['FUID']` does not contain `1`

Comment: @PLB i don't think so. when i put value manually, insted of echohing session variable, it takes just 200ms. yes have indexes.

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION) => Array ( [admin] => 1 [FUID] => 1 )`

Comment: @AliDemirci Have you executed that mysql query manually? I say that executing query causes your problem.

Comment: maybe `$_SESSION['FUID']` is string and your `myWall()` method does something different with strings?

Comment: @PLB: It is clearly mentioned that if the value is passed directly, query seems to be executing normally, so there's no issue with mysql.

Comment: Does print_r($_SESSION) / print_r($_SESSION['FUID']) also take long?

Comment: @AliDemirci: Does echoing $_SESSION['FID'] take long time as well? What happens if you use $_SESSION['FUID'] as parameter but static value (1), inside the function to execute query?

Comment: @Vytautas that was a good point! var_dump says it's a string. i'll check it now.

Comment: @MrSoundless '@J A if i put exit; just after print_r it executes instantly but without an exit function it takes too long.

Comment: @J A static value makes it work well.

Comment: What is `$class` and please post the source code of that class, especially the `myWall` and the `getUser` function. Otherwise you're wasting everbodies time here. And btw. which of those two functions take that long?

Comment: @AliDemirci There are lots of stuff in your code that's bad for performance. To find out which one does it debug your code. Divide in 2 equal part and simply `exit` script. if it takes too long this means that problem is above, if it takes milliseconds than problem is somewhere down and at last you'll find the line that is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is more information.

You should run a profiling tool like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to see exactly where your bottleneck exists. You can analyze the profiling output with a tool like [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net) or [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#cachegrind).

Comment: crazyness. thank you so much. it was all my fault. the problem was with a cURL function that trying to POST some parameter to my old ip which is not available at the moment. thank you. *shy*

Comment: I am glad I could help. Don't feel too bad, it took me quite a few years before I ever thought of using profilers on my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$indexContent = $class->myWall((int)$_SESSION['FUID'], 20, 'no', 15, 'no');
```

Output both SQL queries with static 1 and (int)$_SESSION['FUID'] somewhere if it's still not working. You'll notice differences.

Comment: If both SQL queries are the same - so the problem is not in query. Please, post myWall() and getUser() source.

Comment: @AliDemirci Instead of trying to guess what your methods do would not it be easier to see what they do? Update your question, please.

Comment: Wow. Which one is working slow? Can you comment them all out and than uncomment one by one to detect problem?

Comment: all queries executing in miliseconds. there is no problem with sql. somethings wrong with passing session value to function..

Comment: Nothing can go wrong in passing session variable instead of static 1 in this code. You may try to use tools @GustavBertram advices. May be session variable is messed up somewhere else in this or another class.